# Visual Studio Code and Bash

Tags: bash, scripts, visual-studio-code

I just started learning how to use Linux based systems and bash ,I installed VS Code and added extension [Bash Debugger by rogalmic](https://github.com/rogalmic/vscode-bash-debug) but after executing this simple program:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello world!"
exit 0
```

I got an error in Debug console

```
/home/p/.vscode/extensions/rogalmic.bash-debug-0.3.9/bashdb_dir/command/source.sh: line 41: /dev/stdin: No such device or address
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu or could this be on a Windows system with WSL? The error has nothing to do with your script, it is the bash debugger code that expects to find `/dev/stdin` and fails to find it.

Comment: I am using ubuntu and extension for bash for VS Code but I could not install bashdb because it is way outdated but description of extension said that it is included.
I just statred using Linux few days ago so maybe I am doing something wrong.